# Unable to find version '1.1.2' of package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq'

Tags: kendo-ui, nuget, azure-pipelines

We are using mentioned package in our project and suddenly getting the below error in Azure build pipeline.

The NuGet command failed with exit code(1) and error(Unable to find version '1.1.2' of package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq'. https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq.1.1.2' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'. Errors in packages.config projects Unable to find version '1.1.2' of package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq'. https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq.1.1.2' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'. Unable to find version '1.1.2' of package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq'. https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq.1.1.2' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found below package to fix this issue.
There is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kendo-labs/dlinq-helpers) for the package:

```
GitHub - kendo-labs/dlinq-helpers: Add server paging, filtering and sorting via Dynamic Linq[^]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to find version '1.1.2' of package 'Kendo.DynamicLinq'

That is because this package has been deleted from the nuget gallery.

So, we could no longer available for install/restore:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kendo.DynamicLinq/1.1.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative, you can install it without any refactoring:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoNET.DynamicLinq